# Program crashes when using types from <random> in function

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I'm a beginner in C++, and I just reached some of the new C++11 things, in this case random numbers from "random".

I wrote a simple function that takes to integers, start and end. These integers obviously mark the start and the end of the closed interval in which the random numbers should be.

The function:

```
int randomInt(int start, int end)
{
    using std::default_random_engine;
    using std::uniform_int_distribution;
    using std::random_device;

    random_device rd;
    default_random_engine engine(rd());

    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{ start, end };

    auto res = dist(engine);

    return res;
}
```

When I execute this piece of code in the main function **without** using the function, the program works fine and outputs a random number. But when I call the function with a start and an end, the program crashes with the exception "Illegal instruction", and points me to line 3420 in "xutility". Note: the code compiles, the crash occurs only when running.

€dit: The error in xutility occurs in class _Rng_from_urng, in operator():

```
_Diff operator()(_Diff _Index)
    {   // adapt _Urng closed range to [0, _Index)
    for (; ; )
        {   // try a sample random value
        _Udiff _Ret = 0;    // random bits
        _Udiff _Mask = 0;   // 2^N - 1, _Ret is within [0, _Mask]

        while (_Mask < _Udiff(_Index - 1))
            {   // need more random bits
            _Ret <<= _Bits - 1; // avoid full shift **ERROR IN THIS LINE**
            _Ret <<= 1;
            _Ret |= _Get_bits();
            _Mask <<= _Bits - 1;    // avoid full shift
            _Mask <<= 1;
            _Mask |= _Bmask;
            }

        // _Ret is [0, _Mask], _Index - 1 <= _Mask, return if unbiased
        if (_Ret / _Index < _Mask / _Index
            || _Mask % _Index == _Udiff(_Index - 1))
            return (_Ret % _Index);
        }
    }
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Preview with CTP 4.

Comment: Most of us don't have VS2015 preview installed...care to post the lines around which the crash occurs? Also, what values are you passing to `start` and `end`?

Comment: Edited in post. I pass values like 1 to 10, 1 to 15, 5 to 15 or something around these values.

Comment: Check your compiler settings, make sure it isn't using any instruction set your CPU doesn't support.

Comment: That did it. For some reason I had AVX2 enabled, but my CPU only supports AVX. Guess I played around in the settings.. Thank you!